# Умножение элементов массива js

Tags: javascript

Eсть такой массив: `[5, 123, 556, 78, 3]`.

Kак умножить все элементы массива? B смысле так `5 * 123 * 556 * 78 * 3`.

Comment: попробуйте решить это сами, используйте reduce

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не советую, но как вариант:

```js
console.info(eval([5, 123, 556, 78, 3].join('*')));
```

Подробнее о [`eval()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/eval) и [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

---

Умножение чётных с использованием `eval()`

```js
let array = [5, 123, 556, 78, 3], even = [];

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if(array[i] % 2 === 0) 
    even.push(array[i]);
  else continue;
}

console.info(eval(even.join('*')));
```

---

Умножение чётных с использованием `.reduce`

```js
let array = [5, 123, 556, 78, 3], even = [];

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if(array[i] % 2 === 0) 
    even.push(array[i]);
  else continue;
}

console.info(even.reduce((acc, rec) => acc * rec));
```

Comment: а если нужно умножить те числа которые четные?

Comment: @Мнебезсахара, ну я бы сначала перебрал массив, оставив в нём только чётные, а потом выполнил действие с умножением.

Comment: значит можно сделать так x[n].reduce((acc, rec) => acc *rec)?

Comment: Этот вариант более понятный но можно ли создать новый массив с перебранными элементами и использовать уже этот код?

Comment: @Мнебезсахара, добавил умножение значений с `eval()` и `.reduce`, но **очень советую** использовать вариант с `.reduce`.

Answer (score 7):

Если я правильно поняла вопрос то можно использовать `reduce`. Так получится

```js
const array = [5, 123, 556, 78, 3];
const res = array.reduce((acc, rec) => acc * rec);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: я так понял "array" это имя массива и rec это элемент массива, а что такое acc?

Comment: array -это массив с которым нужно провести работу.
rec - рессивер, элемент массива
acc - аккумулятор,  это результат предидущих иттераций.

Comment: @Мнебезсахара, `acc, rec` - это значения которые передаются внутрь функции reduce, о том какие параметры передаются можно узнать в документации.

Comment: @Yuliia а если нужно умножить те числа которые четные?

Comment: Если нужны только четные  ` array.reduce((acc, rec) => {
  if(rec%2===0){
    return acc*rec
  }
  return acc
})`

Comment: `array.reduce((acc, rec) => acc % 2 ? acc : acc * rec)`

Answer (score 5):

я решу в лоб ;)

```js
var array = [5, 123, 556, 78, 3];
var total = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    total *= array[i];
}

alert(total);
```

Comment: У вас умножается 1 на 5, а не 5 * 123 * 556 * 78 * 3

Comment: @Мнебезсахара, и как это влияет на конечный результат?

Comment: @Мнебезсахара, это ж не проблема, меняете total на первый элемент, и проходите цикл с начальным индексом 1.